# How to check whether a particular app is running or not in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app which requires to check if a particular app is running. I am using the following code but it always tells me using Toast message that the app which by the way is running is not.

Code for the function being used:

```
boolean isNamedProcessRunning(String processName){
  if (processName == null) 
   return false;

  ActivityManager manager = 
     (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
  for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes)
  {
     if (processName.equals(process.processName))
     {
         return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
 }
```

Function call:

```
if(isNamedProcessRunning("WhatsApp")){
    Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),"WhatsApp running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),"WhatsApp Not running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: try to print all manager.getRunningAppProcesses() and check actual name is present, it is really easy... you can check your process name: `if (processName.contains(process.processName))`

Comment: This API - which you were always cautioned against depending on - is now deprecated, you should not expect it to work on recent releases or in the future.  The design intention is that *you should not be able to discover what else is running* as that information was being abused by ill-conceived apps.  And "running" has little significance on Android to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually app process names are like package names "com.android.example", For example "com.android.pandora". Did you try "com.whatsapp" or "com.android.whatsapp" ?

In the loop, print all the processes, this way you would make sure if you got the whatsapp process name correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if your app is running or not you can check with the following code.

```
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo myProcess = new ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo();
    ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState(myProcess);
    Boolean isInBackground = myProcess.importance != ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND;
```